# Changing a character in a class

Tags: jquery

I would like to amend the last character of a string in a particular class.
That is, I would like to change the comma to a full-stop in list items belonging to the class `last` (`li.last`). For example:

```
<li>one,</li>
<li>two,</li>
<li>three,</li>
<li class="last">four,</li>
```

change to:

```
<li class="last">four.</li>
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you do it in the code that creates the HTML?

Comment: Many of your answers are just replacing commas instead of the last character.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text#text2) overload that takes a function, which is useful if you have many such elements:

```
$('li.last').text(function(i, text){
        return text.replace(/,$/, '.');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xVHKd/

Note that you can also use the [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector: `$('li:last-child')`.

Comment: @roXon In programming there is never anything that could be called "**THE** correct solution". The maximum you can go to is "**A** correct solution". And besides, your shift key sticks, please repair it.

Comment: :) Tomalak! I ADORE you. Dam'n, again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.last').each(function(){

   var text = $(this).text();
   text = text.substr(0,text.length-1);  
   text = text+'.';

   $(this).text(text);

});
```

Comment: this will remove any last charactor of the string and replace with a dot

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".last").text($(".last").text().replace(",","."));
```

but I'm not sure if this is a good solution when there are any child elements in the element with the class `last`

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO that will replace all `,` with `.` ! People, sleep sleep moreeeeee. I have my trigger on your -1.... :|

Comment: @roXon - actually, that would replace only the *first* comma - http://jsbin.com/asajas . JavaScript is weird that way - even seemingly simple string replaces need the `/g` flag.

Comment: I know... I wanted just see if someone will +1 my comment! PEOPLE... SLEEEEEP MORE! :)

Answer (score 0):

With **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**:

```
var $last = $('.last');
$last.html($last.html().replace(',' , '.'));
```

This will replace all "," to "." 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
$('li.last').text($('li.last').text().replace(',', '.')
```

Comment: ant that's the exact example to point to a **last character** in a string????? :|

Comment: He "would like to change the comma to a full-stop"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var elem = $('li.last');
elem.text(elem.text().replace(/,^/, "."));
```